What is the EPSG for Czechia (Czech) DMR 5G Lidar Data?
The CUZK geoportal has lidar for Czechia. I have downloaded some LAZ data, and I need to work with the data, and for that, I need the EPSG.
Usually, I use LasTools lasinfo to read the header and get the EPSG, but I cannot see an EPSG code in the header.
When I load the data QGIS, the data is imported and shows 4326 and the CRS screen shows WGS84.
WGS 84
Properties
Geographic (uses latitude and longitude for coordinates)
Dynamic (relies on a datum which is not plate-fixed)
Celestial body: Earth
Based on World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble (EPSG:6326), which has a limited accuracy of at best 2 meters.
Method: Lat/long (Geodetic alias)
WKT
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
    MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
    MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
    MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
    MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
    MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
    MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
    MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)"],
    ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
    AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
        ORDER[1],
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
        ORDER[2],
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    USAGE[
    SCOPE["Horizontal component of 3D system."],
    AREA["World."],
    BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Proj4
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
Extent
-180.00, -90.00, 180.00, 90.00

Here for completeness is the LASINFO header report...
lasinfo (201003) report for '510_5526.laz'
reporting all LAS header entries:
  file signature:             'LASF'
  file source ID:             0
  global_encoding:            1
  project ID GUID data 1-4:   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
  version major.minor:        1.2
  system identifier:          'LAStools (c) by rapidlasso GmbH'
  generating software:        'lasthin64 (220926) commercial'
  file creation day/year:     126/2023
  header size:                227
  offset to point data:       227
  number var. length records: 0
  point data format:          1
  point data record length:   28
  number of point records:    230055
  number of points by return: 203218 22673 3454 638 70
  scale factor x y z:         0.01 0.01 0.01
  offset x y z:               500000 5500000 0
  min x y z:                  510000.01 5526000.02 407.77
  max x y z:                  511999.99 5527999.99 468.32
LASzip compression (version 3.4r3 c2 50000): POINT10 2 GPSTIME11 2
reporting minimum and maximum for all LAS point record entries ...
  X             1000001    1199999
  Y             2600002    2799999
  Z               40777      46832
  intensity           8        240
  return_number       1          6
  number_of_returns   1          6
  edge_of_flight_line 0          0
  scan_direction_flag 0          0
  classification      8          8
  scan_angle_rank     0          0
  user_data           0          0
  point_source_ID   716        720
  gps_time -34955920.202086 -34953009.198094
number of first returns:        203218
number of intermediate returns: 16
number of last returns:         229908
number of single returns:       203087
WARNING: there are 2 points with return number 6
overview over number of returns of given pulse: 203087 22792 3462 642 70 2 0
histogram of classification of points:
      230055  keypoint (8)

I have tried using 4326 and the software I am using reports that this is not the correct EPSG for this data file. Can anyone tell me the EPSG code for this data?

If it's not in the LAZ header, you'll have to look for that information in the CUZK geoportal.

From CUZK: EPSG code 5514 S-JTSK / Krovak East North is an equivalent to the existing ESRI code 102067

Yes, that worked!  Many thanks Pointdump.  Would you like to post as an answer, so that I can accept and give you the credit?

From the Geoportal ČÚZK:

EPSG code 5514 S-JTSK / Krovak East North is an equivalent to the
existing ESRI code 102067


This has helped me greatly, much appreciated.
